# could not stat file - c

Tags: c, stat

I need to stat a file to get the size of it. I also need to provide the name of the file as a command line argument. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int N = 300;
    int L = 1000;
    char Nseq[N][L];

    FILE *myfile;
    char *token;
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *line;
    int lenline;
    char filename[100];
    strcpy(filename, "/path/");
    char name[100];
    strcpy(name, argv[1]);
    strcat(filename, name);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");
    printf("%s\n", filename);

    int err;
    struct stat st;
    int n = 0;

    err = stat(filename,&st);
    if (err < 0) {
        printf("could not stat file %s", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    lenline = st.st_size + 1;

    line = malloc(lenline);

    myfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (myfile == NULL) {
        printf("could not open file %s", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(line, lenline, myfile) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(line, s);
        while (token != NULL && n<N) {
            strcpy(Nseq[n], token);
            printf("%s\t%u\n", token, n);
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            n++;
        }
    }

    fclose(myfile);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
/path/file.txt

could not stat file /path/file.txt
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? 
how can I fix it?
thank you!

Comment: Please consider trimming down your code sample to a minimum needed to show your issue; all the stuff after the "cannot stat" message is unnecessary and mostly a distraction.  Trim out what you can to the minimum.  But do you know the file actually exists?

Comment: Please produce a [mre]

Comment: Call [perror](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) in the error path to get more detailed error msg. `/path` is an unusual path. Are you sure that actually exists?

Comment: Do `ls -l /path/file.txt` from your shell.  What does it show?

Comment: `I also need to provide the name of the file as a command line argument.` - Why are you prepending `/path` and then appending `.txt` if the goal was to (ostensibly) provide this information on the command line?

Comment: OT: regarding; `strcpy(name, argv[1]);`  Always check `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user before accessing anything beyond `argv[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page of `stat` (2) says: On success, zero (`0`) is returned. On error, `-1` is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.

You don't actually use `errno` and basically are causing your own error message to be a rather unhelpful variant of "something went wrong".

Actually use `errno`, implicitly by calling

```
perror("stat");
```

or explicitly by calling

```
fprintf(stderr, "could not stat file %s: %s", filename, strerror(errno));
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem, most likely, is that you're prepending `/path` and appending `.txt` and there is no actual file at the path you're constructing before calling `stat`.  If you focus only on successfully `stat`ing the file, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  const char* filename = argv[1];

  printf("Calling stat(%s)...", filename);

  int err;
  struct stat st;

  err = stat(filename, &st);
  if (err < 0) {
    printf("failed with error %d (%s)\n", err, strerror(errno));
    return err;
  } else {
    printf("succeeded\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

At the very least you'll see exactly why `stat` is failing and it will help show why you're code isn't working properly.